# heroku sample application error

Tags: java, deployment, heroku

I am doing the sample application here https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-embedded-tomcat

I have run the application using 'mvn package' and the build is success..but when am running the script using "sh target/bin/webapp" then am getting the below error.Sir please help..thanks

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\srinivasa\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.0.RELEASE\sriniv as>sh
>   target/bin/webapp Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: launch/Main Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: launch.Main
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) Could not find the main class: launch.Main.  Program will exit.

@james sir please do help am getting this error

```
C:\Documents and Settings\srinivasa\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.0.RELEASE\testhe
roku\target\bin>webapp.bat
configuring app with basedir: C:\Documents and Settings\srinivasa\Documents\work
space-sts-2.9.0.RELEASE\testheroku\target\bin\.\src\main\webapp
Apr 16, 2012 8:12:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 16, 2012 8:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Apr 16, 2012 8:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.22
Apr 16, 2012 8:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Documents and Settings\srin
ivasa\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.0.RELEASE\testheroku\target\bin\src\main\webap
p does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.
java:140)
```

sir my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.heroku.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>embeddedTomcatSample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>embeddedTomcatSample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>embeddedTomcatSample</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>main.java.launch.Main</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and am using same Main.java,HelloServlet.java,index.jsp

Answer (score 4):

On Windows you need to run:

```
target\bin\webapp.bat
```

Comment: :::term
web: sh target/bin/webapp.....sir how can i create a procfile in windows??  procfile is a classfile or what it is exactly please help

Comment: @user1160126 - run `target\bin\webapp.bat` from the directory `C:\Documents and Settings\srinivasa\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.0.RELEASE\testheroku`, not `webapp.bat` from the target/bin directory

Comment: The `Procfile` is only used on Heroku, not locally.

Comment: @JamesWard Thanks a lot, I wasted too much time typing whats on Heroku's page which is `target/bin/webapp.bat` and I kept getting 'target' is unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM tells you that it cannot find the class launch.Main.  You need to set the classpath for the JVM to find it:

```
java -cp <f> launch.Main
```

where `<f>` is the path to the folder that contains the launch directory (e.g. target/bin)

Comment: Thank you sir..am going in the right way..please help..first am taking new project as "dynamic web project" in my spring source tool suite..then i got only 'src' folder..i didnt get these folders "src/main/java/launch"..do i need to manually create these folders??..please help is this right way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring, but the source folders should be ok (the source compiled ok, you got a runtime error)

Comment: Sir in the same application in pom.xml..these are appear..how can i get these files?? please help me   <groupId>com.heroku.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>embeddedTomcatSample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>embeddedTomcatSample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>

Comment: Those should be downloaded automatically by maven when you compile the project.  Run `mvn install` to build the project, then try `mvn exec:exec` -- if the pom.xml is set up that way, it will start the program with the right classpath

Comment: Sir got error when i have done mvn exec:exec-- [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (d
efault-cli) on project embeddedTomcatSample: The parameters 'executable' for goa
l org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid -> [Help
 1]

Comment: OK, then the pom is not set up that way...  Either [modify it](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) to allow exec:exec or specify the classpath on the java command line

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still care about this, but did you do:

```
set REPO=%UserProfile%\.m2\repository
```

?  The target/bin/webapp script that appassembler generates relies on that environment variable.